# How to export javascript generated report to pdf?

Tags: java, javascript

I made a reporting engine with javascript for my project...
The problem is with printing..
Although with page-break and css i can produce a good looking report, i want to export that report to a pdf in order to be printed better without ,the url,page title and other stuff that browsers add.
Note in Chrome there isnt page setup!!!

I am using java for server side.

i think sending via ajax the Html of the report somehow and return a url for the pdf report maybe...
i am looking for a good tool for this 
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do send the data server-side, **[iText](http://itextpdf.com/)** is a great free, open source library for generating PDFs from Java.

What I do is generate the report directly to the response stream after setting the content type of the response to `application/pdf` and setting a `Content-Disposition` header to either `attachment; filename=foo.pdf` (if I want to hint to the browser that it should offer a download) or `inline; filename=foo.pdf` if I want to hint to the browser to show it in the brower's UI.

For what you're doing, perhaps you want to write a file server-side in case someone requests another copy of the report with the same parameters and such, but if not, writing directly to the servlet's `OutputStream` would be the way to go.

*(Caveat: I have to admit not having actually used the Java version of iText, but only because I haven't needed to generate PDFs from Java yet. I'm doing the above using iTextSharp, the .Net port of iText, from server-side Javascript [yes, really] and it works a treat.)*

Comment: On top of iText, there's the Flying Saucer project, which does a surprisingly good job of transforming XHTML (with CSS, including lots of the print-related goodies from CSS3) into PDF.  I use Freemarker to bind data into XHTML reports, and then Flying Saucer to make the PDF's and it's awesome. https://xhtmlrenderer.dev.java.net/

Comment: @Pointy: Ooooh, nifty! Have to check that out.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather generate the report on the server side, based on the data, using JasperReports.

You can send the html to server side and use iText or JasperReports or [OpenOffice api](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=53745) to generate a pdf.

Comment: would jasper etc let me fit the data in a a4 page?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how much you have invested in your Javascript solution.  Typically I would agree that it is much better to produce the report server-side since you'll have more options and probably a more maintainable result using Jasper or Docmosis or somesuch.

You could send the html of the page back to the server and have a system there that can read it and render it into PDF, but you've done a round-trip more than you need to, and it sounds like a harder and more fragile way to produce a PDF.